# How to implement the Tea Algorithm with objective c?

Tags: c, objective-c, encryption

i am a new object-c developer,i wanna implement Tea Algorithm, but i don't know more about the byte infomation ,so i cant control the string byte stream .who can tall me how to implement this Algorithm. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at wiki about the TEA algorithm there's C source code example.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XXTEA

Objective-C is an extension on C. That means that any valid C code will work in an Objective-C program. So if you have the C source code, just use that.

Comment: I've implemented the TEA algorithm in a old Objective-C project, the code on Wikipedia works just fine.